# How can I code in python with a public and private key?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to code  with public and private key. However I keep getting a error when I am trying to encrypt. this is what i have so far:

```
import random

Primes = [2,3,5,7,9,11,13,15]

p = random.choice(Primes)
q = random.choice(Primes)
n = p*q
z = (p-1)*(q-1)

deck = list(range(1,z))

e = random.choice(deck)

d = (z + 1)/e
a= divmod(d*e,z)

PublicKey = (e,n)
PrivateKey = (d,n)

input = raw_input ('Write text: ')
input = input.lower()
message = []
for character in input:
    number = ord(character)
    message.append(number)


#Encrypt
for character in message:
    c = message**e % n 

#Decrypt
for character in c:
    decryption = c**d % n
```

The program is running fine until I get by the encryption part. The error I got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/rsa2.py", line 30, in <module>
    c = message**e % n
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: You made a typo, it should be: `c = c**e % n ` You also have issues with your decrypt loop, ...

Comment: Or rather, you convert the *entire* message in to a single integer that gets raised to the `e`th power (mod `n`). You are trying to raise a list of integers to the `e`th power.

Comment: It should not be c**e. I want that the number of a character in message will pe powerd. for instance: message = hello. c = ord(h)**e % n .

Comment: @hfdgdfgfagfgfgfgf But you aren't doing any sort of aggregation. `c` gets overwritten each time through the loop (assuming you meant something like `c = character ** e % n`), so when you go to decrypt, `c` is only one small part of the original message.

Comment: Something like `c = reduce(lambda a, c: ord(c)*128 + a, message, 0); c = c ** e % n` is closer to what you want.

Comment: @chepner can you explain it in easier python2.7 language. I am a starting user of python and am not so good at such complex solutions.

Comment: The idea is to treat the string as a number with (7-bit ASCII) characters as digits. `"hello"` gets reduced as  `ord("h")*128**4 + ord("e")*128**3 + ord("l")*128**2 + ord("l")*128 + ord("o")`. The use of 128 as the base assumes that `ord(c) < 128` for any character in your input message. `reduce` is just a convenient way to implement [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Comment: As a simpler example, `int(message, base=36)` will return a single integer value as long as `message` only contains numerical digits and letters of the same case (i.e., all upper or all lower, mixed case not allowed).